# Completion suggester across multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch 6.x does not support multiple type mappings in a single index. So I have for example 2 indices:

- location
- postcode

I want to have autocomplete functionality (I use completion suggester) using both indices. Is it possible?

This is my example of mapping `location` index:

```
{
  "location": {
    "mappings": {
      "location": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },          
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "preserve_separators": false,
            "preserve_position_increments": false,
            "max_input_length": 50
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And `postcode` index:

```
{
  "postcode": {
    "mappings": {
      "postcode": {
        "properties": {
          "code": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "preserve_separators": true,
            "preserve_position_increments": true,
            "max_input_length": 50
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's possible to do a request if I just skip index name in a request, e.g.

```
POST _search
{
  "suggest": {
    "suggestion": {
      "prefix": "abc",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It searches in both indices but the result is incorrect. For example in the previous request we're searching for values start with `abc`. If `location` index contains many documents with values start with `abc`, e.g. `abcd` or `abcde`, then the response won't contain values from `postcode` index even if it contains exact value `abc`.

**EDITED:**

I wasn't right about incorrect behavior across multiple indices. If we use only one index (e.g. location) and PUT one more document with suggest value `abc`, then we will see the same behavior. It happens because all results have the same `score = 1`.

So how can I have a bigger score for exact matches?

I found this closed ticket (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4759) but I don't understand what should I do to achive appropriate behaviour? It does not work out of the box.

Comment: I am curious about your analyzer for "suggest" in "location". It says "autocomplete". Is this a custom analyzer? If yes, can you share more details about it?

Comment: @sammy yes, this is my custom analyzer. But as I understand the problem is not connected to analyzer. I will change it to `simple` as well. The problem is that Completion Suggester works only per index. FST is built per index. So in my case a have 2 graphs. I'm looking for apportunity to combine these graphs.